# Second Moment Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was hoping someone can please verify if my reasoning is correct or make any suggestions.

Question to prove: Let $Y_{1}, Y_{2},...$ be independent random variables with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^{2}$. Let $X_{n}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}-n\sigma^{2}$ and show that $\lbrace X_{n} \rbrace$ is a martingale.

My answer: Here we take $\mathcal{F_{n}}=\sigma(Y_{0},...,Y_{n})$. We also note that $E(X_{n})=0$. Now,

$E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_{n}})$

$=E(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}Y_{k}\right)^{2}-(n+1)\sigma^{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}})$

$=E({\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}+Y_{n+1}\right)}^{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}})-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$

$=E(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}+2(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})(Y_{n+1})+({Y_{n+1}})^{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}})-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$

$=E(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}})+0+E((Y_{n+1})^{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}})-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$

$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}+E((Y_{n+1})^{2})-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$

$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}+\sigma^{2}-(n+1)\sigma^{2}$

$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right)^{2}-n\sigma^{2}$

$=X_{n}$.

How does that look? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, my answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed. You could shorten this somewhat, writing $X_{n+1}=X_n+Y_{n+1}$, using the same computations.